# Search for a specific part of a string and cut it out

Tags: string, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord.js bot that checks for a certain string and logs it in a txt file. So far I have:

```
  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in msg) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(msg[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
  }
  if (foundInText) {
    let data=message.content;
    fs.appendFile("saidmessages.txt", `${data}
    `,function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
    });
  }
```

What I have so far works. However, for my purposes, I only want to log a specific part of a message. Currently, it logs the whole message. Is there a way I can check the string for a specific part and only log that part of the string?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `#includes`. Also, if you know what the string is, you dont have to cut it out.

```js
let exampleString = "this is a string of words I know";

if (exampleString.split(" ").includes("this")) { //this splits the string into an array, then finds an element that matches "this" and returns a boolean value as to whether it exists
   //use fs to write "this" to the file
}
```

Another possible way you could achieve this is with a `Regular Expression`:

```js
let exampleString = "this is a string of words I know";

var subString = exampleString.replace(new RegExp('.*' + "a"), '');
```

This RegExp cuts the text after a certain word(/s).
The `subString` variable will therefore hold `string of words I know`.

Comment: This approach will only work if the substring is a single word - a better solution would be able to handle a multi-word substring as well.

Comment: you are correct, I am about to add a RegExp solution also